# It is just like him to be late

Tags: meaning, pronouns

What a strange construction is it? Why does it sound so strange to me, Ukrainian fella? For instance, why "him" instead of "he".
And, first of all, what does it mean? I even cannot translate it correctly.

Comment: Great question, although you might want to consider asking questions like this at the site for [ell.SE]. You're welcome to stay at both places, but the other site was set up for questions like this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why "him" instead of "he"?

Because that is the idiom: *like* takes a complement in the objective case:

> My son is like *me*.
>   Look at these pictures. This bird is like **them**.

*Just* here means "exactly".  So *just like him* means "exactly like him".

When we say that a behavior or opinion or attitude is "just like" somebody, we are comparing that behavior/opinion/attitude to those which they typically exhibit: it is "just like" what we expect of them.

The structure here is what grammarians call a 'cleft construction', in which a phrase which occurs late in the 'basic sentence' is moved to become the complement of an *It is* clause, and is followed by the rest of the sentence.

```
To be late is just like him.  >> It is just like him to be late
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So the sentence means "Being late is his typical behavior".

But it is not a simple statement of fact: it implies considerable irritation with that behavior, too. On the other hand, as J.R. points out, using the phrase with a positive behavior implies considerable admiration: "It's **just like her** to spend her weekends working for Habitats for Humanity."

Comment: Just a footnote: This expression often carries some emotion with it, as you say, but that emotion is not always negative. For example, "Did you hear Julie baked a pie for her neighbors?" "She did? It's just like her to be so nice." The construction can be used to express approval as easily as disapproval.

Comment: @J.R. You're quite right, and I need to add that.

Answer (score 4):

It's *him* instead of *he* because the pronoun is an object, not the subject.

As for the meaning, let me try to give a couple rough paraphrases:

> He is late all the time!
>   It seems like we are always waiting for him.

Essentially, the speaker is saying that *lateness* is one of his character traits – this fellow is habitually late.

I can see how it would be an odd construct the first time you run across it. It's just like English to be so confounding.

Answer (score -2):

Simply - "It is just like him to be late" displays a moment of recognition. The person "him" is typically late & this has just been re-affirmed. The word "him" rather than "he" is more specific to (or towards) that person. "him" points the finger, whereas "he" describes "him" - does, can, will, is, should . . etc. The sentence(s) could say "It is just like *him* to be late. *He* is always late."

Comment: *He* is no less specific than *him*.

Comment: @Matt Эллен. I disagree. _Him_ highlights a person, directs at them whereas _he_ will be followed by descriptors about _him_

Comment: I don't see what that has to do with specificity.

Comment: @Matt Эллен. What I'm trying to say is that _him_ is specific _to_ a person while _he_ is specific _about_ them.

Comment: Should I have used the word immediate instead?

Comment: Use of _him_ or _he_ depends on where the pronoun is used in the sentence. _He ate fish for dinner last night. I know that's true, because I asked him. That's what he told me, and I believed him. It was grilled salmon, with a tangy orange glaze. I told him, "That sounds delicious." He didn't argue with me. It's just like him to cook something so fancy, even though he's a bachelor who lives alone and cooks only for himself. I think he worked in a fancy restaurant when he was younger – I'll have to ask him about that_. That's ten _he's_ & _him's;_ as @Matt says, they don't differ in specificity.